# how to submit a jquery mobile pop form via ajax in cakephp

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, cakephp, jquery-mobile

i have been trying to submit a jquery mobile form using ajax in cakephp but the form does not submit, i don't know what could be wrong, here is my controller code:

```
public function add() {
    if ($this->request->is('ajax')) {
        $this->request->data['Room']['user_id'] = $this->Session->read('Auth.User.id');
        $this->Room->User->updateAll(array("User.room_count"=>'User.room_count+1'),array('User.id'=> $this->Session->read('Auth.User.id') ));
        $this->Room->create();
        if ($this->Room->save($this->request->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The room has been saved.'));

            $this->render('AjaxRoom','ajax');
        } else {
            $this->render('AjaxRoom','ajax');

        }

    }
    $users = $this->Room->User->find('list');
    $this->set(compact('users'));
}
```

and here is my view code:

```
<div id="sent" style="display:none;">Updating...</div>

  <div id="success"></div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
   //<![CDATA[
  $(document).ready(function () {
  $("#RoomIndexForm").bind("submit", function (event) {
   $.ajax({
   async:true, 
    beforeSend:function (XMLHttpRequest) {$("#sent").show(500)}, 
   complete:function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus)      {$("#sent").hide(500);$("#TalkViewForm").each (function(){this.reset();});

 //$("#refresh").load(location.href + " #refresh");

    }, 
   data:$("#RoomIndexForm").serialize(), 
     dataType:"html", 
    success:function (data, textStatus) { //$("#success").html(data); 

    },
  type:"POST", 
 url: "<?php echo $this->Html->url(array('controller' => 'rooms',    'action' => 'add')); ?>"});
    return false;
  });
});
//]]>
 </script> 
 <div data-role="popup" id="popupRoom" data-theme="a" class="ui-corner-  all">
  <?php echo     $this->Form->create('Room',array('role'=>'form','url'=>array('controller'=>'r        ooms', 'action'=>'add'))); ?>
   <div style="padding:10px 20px;">
       <h3>Add Room</h3>
      <?php echo $this->Form->input('name', array(
            'label' => false,
            'placeholder'=>'Room Name'));
    ?>

     <?php
        echo $this->Form->input('description', array(
            'label' => false,
            'type' => 'textarea',
            'maxlength'=>"140",
            'placeholder'=>'Describe Your room briefly.'));
            ?>

             <?php 
            $accountValues = array();
      foreach ($categories as $key => $value) {
           $accountValues[$value] = $value;
            } 
        $categories = $accountValues;

            echo $this->Form->select('category',array(

            'options' =>$categories), array(
            'label' => false,
          'empty'   => false
        ));
         ?>

         <?php
            //echo $this->Form->input('filename', array('type' => 'file','label'=>'Upload an Image'));
            //echo $this->Form->input('file_dir', array('type' => 'hidden'));
            ?>

            <?php
        echo $this->Form->input('is_private', array(
            'label' => 'Do you want a private Room ?   If No, just ignore this field.',
            'type'=>'checkbox',
            ));
         ?>

          <?php echo $this->Form->submit('Create',array('class'=>'ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-b ui-btn-icon-left ui-icon-check')); ?>

        </div>
        <?php echo $this->Form->end(); ?>
       </div>
```

please how do i achieve this functionality? any help is welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

The Html Helper does not support url i think:

```
$this->Html->url(array('controller' => 'rooms', 'action' => 'add'))
```

Try to use this instead:

```
$this->Html->link(['controller' => 'Rooms', 'action' => 'add'])
```

Another way is the url builder (http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/url.html):

```
$this->Url->build(['controller' => 'Rooms', 'action' => 'add'])
```